# Why is JEST testing giving "Could not find "store" error when call setState?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test this:
(I need to confirm that when selectedDevice is called with DESKTOP prop, it calls openModal and that method sets the state of modalOpen to true)

```
  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalOpen: true });
  };


  selectedDevice = () => {
    const { device } = this.props;
    const isMobile = device === MOBILE;
    if (isMobile) {
      this.closeWindow();
    } else {
      this.openModal();
    }
  };
```

and I'm testing like this (with JEST)

```
test('should openModal be called', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Component
      {...sampleProps}
      deviceType={DESKTOP}
    />);

    const selectedDevice = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'selectedDevice');
    selectedDevice();
    expect(wrapper.state().modalActivated).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Apparently, it seems to be reaching the openModal method in my component. However, I'm getting this error:

```
    Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Styled(Component))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Styled(Component))".

      36 | 
      37 |   openModal = () => {
    > 38 |     this.setState({ modalOpen: true });
         |          ^
```

I saw another solutions to that error message, but nothing seems to work for this specific error.
I already tried wrapping the component inside a Provider component with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're using a `component` which is wrapped inside of the `connect HOC` from `react-redux` and the `connect HOC` needs the redux `Provider` component with a state.

Your code should be something like this:

```
test("should openModal be called", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={CreateANewStoreForTest}>
      <Component {...sampleProps} deviceType={DESKTOP} />
    </Provider>
  );

  const selectedDevice = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "selectedDevice");
  selectedDevice();
  expect(wrapper.state().modalActivated).toEqual(true);
});
```

and for data on how to create a store read the [DOC here](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore)

Comment: Thanks Taghi. But how can I create a store for test?

Comment: It's the same as you're `redux` store. read the link I attached for more information

Comment: and if the answer was helpful to you, try to give an upvote and accept the answer

Comment: I did that but now the line "const selectedDevice = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "selectedDevice");" is giving me an error saying that "Cannot spy the selectedDevice property because it is not a function; undefined given instead"

Comment: That's currect because you're wrapper is not `mounted Component` anymore and it's the /transaction/request`redux Provider` you need to do a query to get the `Component` and then make a `jest.spyOn` on it